# Swift: UIImageView Scrollview not working when zooming

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I'm trying to add the ability to zoom to my app for my imageView but it's not working. I added the imageView to scrollView and added this code, not working at all.

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Add Image
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(groupChoice)_\(insideChoice)")

    // Add Zoom
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10.0
    scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
    scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = false
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
    scrollView.contentSize = imageView.frame.size
    imageView.clipsToBounds = false
}

func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return imageView
}
```

Comment: I am working with a scrollView now, but I do not explicit set the contentSize and it works with me perfectly. I think something is wrong with your constraints

Comment: I don't have any constraints on this view controller and I took off the line `contentSize` but it's still not working

Comment: No constraints?! Impossible if this is your full code.

Comment: I'm confused, isn't constraints used to set up auto layouts in the storyboard?

Comment: Not necessarily, you can make them in code as well. Without constrains you can not do much...

Comment: I haven't set any constrains in storyboard or by code as you can see, that is my full code for that UIViewController

Comment: Missing LIne scrollView.delegate = self